# Active directory web service (ADWS) is missing on Windows 10 Pro

Tags: powershell, windows-10, windows-10-desktop, powershell-5.1

I want to run below command on the Windows 10 Powershell but I am getting error:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-ADUser -filter *
Get-ADUser: Unable to find a default server with Active Directory Web Services running.
```

After googling error I got few links for starting the ADWS service.
But I am not able to find any document/link to install the ADWS service on my Windows 10 Pro Laptop.

I did try to find the instruction to install the ADWS but no instructions found.
Can someone please point me to the steps to install the ADWS for Windows 10 Pro.

I have all the "RSAT" modules installed on my Laptop.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-WindowsCapability -Online -Name "RSAT*" | Add-WindowsCapability -Online
```

I have read below links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/services-hub/premier/health/remediation-steps-ad/configure-the-active-directory-web-services-adws-to-start-automatically-on-all-servers

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/b84c5dd6-cbf7-43ca-9a6a-5696360d3957/active-directory-web-service-not-available?forum=winserverDS

Comment: ADWS is to be installed on a Domain Controller, not a member computer. Perhaps you should go talk to whoever managed Active Directory in your environment?

Comment: I wan to run the Get-ADUser from my Laptop and it requires ADWS on my Laptop. Please refer to my question.

Comment: You're misinterpreting the error message - it's not trying to find ADWS on your machine, it's trying to locate a server on the network that has ADWS running. How many Domain Controllers do you have in the domain?

Comment: If so then I am not sure why all the google links are pointing to the steps to start the ADWS service from the "services.msc". I have single Domain Controller in my AD. If we need to install/start the ADWS on my Azure AD how it can be done? How to resolve the Get-ADUser error?

Comment: Alright, assuming your laptop is a member of the domain and the domain controller is running on 2008R2 or a newer version of Windows Server, you shouldn't have to do anything (ADWS will be automatically installed when you install the ADDS Role). Try `Get-ADUser -filter * -Server nameOfDomainController`

Comment: I am not sure if my Laptop is member of domain controller, how to check and how to configure? Also how do I get nameOfDomainController?

Comment: Not a "member of a domain controller", a member  _of the domain_. Check with `dsregcmd /status|Select-String DomainJoined`

Comment: For the "dsregcmd" command I am getting "DomainJoined : NO". My AD is NOT running on any standalone server, it is running on Azure cloud. I was trying to do something similar to the question https://serverfault.com/questions/203123/unable-able-to-run-remote-powershell-using-active-directory. I did connect to AD by following the steps given in the link https://xenit.se/blog/2018/01/05/join-windows-10-computer-azure-active-directory/

Comment: you can try running this $env:USERDNSDOMAIN to get the AD server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Powershell ActiveDirectory examples that you find on the web usually assume you are using a PC thats on the domain, and you are logged into that PC as a domain user. But often these days thats not the case.

These days people are often logged into their own PC as 'Joe' and connected via VPN to a company's domain, with the DC running in Azure somewhere.

And when its like that, you have to tell the cmdlet where the DC is, and supply some credentials. So you do that like this:

```
Get-ADUser -Server (name or IP address of DC) -Credential (Get-Credential) -filter *
```

The 'Get-Credential' bit will interactively ask you for credentials - you need to supply credentials for a user in the domain

Answer (score 1):

```
$Server = (nslookup $env:USERDNSDOMAIN)[0].split(' ')[2]
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Comment: people who dont understand what this is, he is using $env:USERDNSDOMAIN to get the domain name of the AD Server