# Windows 10 - AD LDS - New-ADOrganizationalUnit - Unable to contact the server

Tags: powershell, windows-10, adlds

I have installed ADLDS in my Windows 10 (21H2) machine, we don't have any domain controller, the idea is to use AD LDS for user management in our Plant SCADA application. I am trying to create an OU via powershell cmdlets. But i get the following error:

[New-ADOrganizationalUnit : Unable to contact the server. This may be because this server does not exist, it is currently down, or it does not have the Active Directory Web Services running.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5Bho.png)

The same powershell cmdlets works fine with AD LDS instance installed in a server 2019. But i get issues when i run same powershell cmdlets in my windows 10 machine. When i checked the Server 2019 i can see there is a windows service "ADWS" running, but i don't find this in my windows 10 machine, so i am not sure if this is the issue as said in the error. i installed the RSAT:ADLS tools from optional feature, so couldn't figure out how to get this feature(ADWS) and get my cmdlets work in my windows 10 machine. ( i am able to create OU via ADSI edit, but the idea is we want to use powershell to automate) i would really appreciate if some one could shed somelight on this ( all my google search results are leading me nowhere :( )

Comment: From cmd.exe type following to get name : ipconfig/all

Comment: Thanks, but I have modified the hostname in my cmdlets before running it in my Windows 10 PC. So i dont think its the name issue.

Comment: Read following.  You may have a credential issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72200372/active-directory-web-service-adws-is-missing-on-windows-10-pro

Comment: Thanks, i went through this link already, i did try with the cmdlets to prompt credential, but it wasn't helpful. And they were talking about ADWS in a domain controller, but in my case there is no domain controller, i am trying to use my windows 10 as a standalone PC, and use the AD LDS for usermanagement for our SCADA application installed in same PC. i want the powershell to look at the instance that i created in local  PC and add the OU to the ADLDS path i mentioned in cmdlets.

Comment: You need to determine the configuration of the SCADA network.  I suspect you do not have a route to the server.  Using from cmd.exe >Ping IP (or machine name) will help confirm problem. If ping doesn't work with IP also try machine name.  Once you get the connection you can use either the IP or machine name as the sever in the PS cmdlet.  The cmdlet is using port  389.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCADA.  Port 389 reserved for Apple LDAP.  It may blocked by a virus checker.  See following for more info : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCADA

Comment: The SCADA application may not be on your company network and may need to get to machine either on the SCADA network or through the Internet.  I had similar issue trying to install a Raspberry PI on my company network.  Had to get special permission to add a non window machine on network since company app was blocking the connection.  It may be better to use a port number greater than 1000 so virus checkers will ignore.  I usually use a port number > 10,000